# Can't customise bootstrap-4 css with my own custom css file

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-4, styling

Here is my code to link my two stylesheets together with the custom css fie second as that is the way to do it i believe.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/custom.css">
</head>
```

Check the image below for file paths

[See file locations here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPKKV.png

I have tried for hours to get this to work, I'm not a great coder and this i due for deadline quite soon as a part of my A-Level any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom CSS filepath -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/custom.css">
```